# Can I expect some heap memory locations to have faster access than others in C++?

Tags: c++, performance, memory, memory-management

Suppose I am using a fixed-size memory-pool in C++ to preallocate memory and prevent calls to `new` and `delete`. It follows some simple logic:

- Allocate `n` memory blocks
- Push all memory blocks to a stack
- When the users requests memory, pop a block from the stack
- When the user returns memory, push the block to the stack
- If the stack is empty and the user requests memory, crash the application

Now, stack operations are very fast, but this scheme may be inefficient if some memory locations are faster to read and write than others. I *think* this might be the case due how the CPU works.

For example, suppose this is my memory-pool:

```
Stack:
2 4 5

Pool: 
0 1 2 3 4 5
X X - X - -
```

Sections `2`, `4` and `5` are *unused*, and `5` is on the top of the stack.

My current system would give the user block `5` on request, but block `2` might be faster to use because it is closer to the other memory that is in use.

My questions are:

- Is some heap memory faster to read and write than other areas?
- If so, what data-structures would be better than a stack to prioritize some memory blocks over others?

Comment: Such micro-optimizations seem like really making things more complex than they are. I see many considerations: did you prove that an hypothetical faster memory location affects performance in your situation? How can you guarantee that all cpu architectures behave consistently with that regard? How can you even guarantee that the same cpu architecture on different runs behaves consistently? I don't see this going anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean? Why would some memory blocks be faster than others? RAM memory has the same speed for all regions. Or do you mean CPU cache - L1, L2, L3?

Comment: @Jack I think OP is not expecting a particular memory location is faster, but that it is faster to use memory locations that are close together, which is true in general afaik.

Comment: @tobi303: he's asking "Is some heap memory faster to read and write than other areas?" which seems quite a general question. If everything revolves around caching of blocks in memory then my same questions apply: since caching is something that your program doesn't know about then you are just guessing, which can be done for a specific problem in a specific situation but not in general.

Comment: @Jack OP writes: "...but block 2 might be faster to use because it is closer to the other memory that is in use." so I interpret the question as "Is it faster to use chunks of memory that are close together", not as "is there one particular region that is always faster"

Comment: Not sure how much you know about the topic, but I think you might be interested in reading about [non-uniform memory access (NUMA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access). I'm no expert, so just leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Your strategy of pre-allocating fixed sized blocks is a good strategy for increasing performance of many different types of operations. But the only heap memory that is "faster" than other heap memory are they bytes currently paged in or in the L1 cache. You didn't mention what size your blocks were.  About the only thing you might want to consider is optimizing around the cache line size (64 bytes on Intel). But that's a optimization only for very specialized scenarios.

Comment: How big are these blocks of memory?  If they are larger than a cache line it is probably moot.

Answer (score 0):

The heap memory is not faster or slower than the stack memory. Calling to the operating system for allocation is expensive.

If you want to write an optimized/fast code it is preferable to use sequential data to optimize the processor cache. Thats all. The best means to do that is `std::array`- with almost no overhead and `std::vector`-with some overhead but it gives you the option to resize. You can also use `std::vector::reserve` to do only one allocation when you know the number of the entries.

Comment: This does not really answer my question. The memory pool is already a continuous block of memory. The question is, how should I prioritize the blocks that are selected at run-time.

Comment: @sdgfsdh This depends on how big are your blocks compared to the cache of the processor. 
The work of the processor cache rather complicated but it is okay to view it like it will load a `CACHESIZE` of data from the address who was found in the memmory(because it was not in the cache).  If block 1 and 2 are right next to each other and the block is significanlty smaller than the cache you might not get a cache miss when you try to get the second block after the first block.

Comment: This is wrong. The stack IS generally faster because it's always nearly guaranteed to be in the L1 cache due to it being last-in-first-out.

Comment: @user997112 It is not. If you look at the things that I said you'll see that I'm speaking in case that there is no cache. In the second paragraph, I'm mentioning the cache and the fact that it will make the program faster.
I'm quite aware how the cache works and It is preferable to keep small objects there.